# Mi contraseña encriptada no funciona en el login

Tags: php, contraseña

Mi problema es que mi login no confirma la contraseña encriptada. codigo

```
 if(isset($_POST['seleccion'])){

    $email = $_POST['correo'];
    $contrasena = $_POST['contraseña'];
    $encrip = password_hash($contrasena, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    $sql = mysqli_query($connex, "SELECT * FROM logi WHERE email='$email' and contraseña='$contrasena' ");

    if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0){

      if (password_verify($contrasena, $encrip)) {
       
         echo "Se encontro el usuario, $email.";

      }

    } else {

       echo "no se encontro el usuario";


 }
```

en otra hoja tengo el registro con la contraseña encriptada...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

BASE DE DATOS

las contraseñas sin encriptar estan rayadas en rojo .

Comment: Tú guardas la contraseña sin cifrar en la BD?????? Y luego comparas la contraseña que recibiste con la variable en la que tú mismo cifraste esa contraseña y preguntas si coinciden???

Comment: No, en la BD si esta cifrado, pero cuando le doy a login no se comparan no son iguales

Comment: @LuisChaves por que la contraseña que deberías evaluar dentro del método es la que obtienes de la base de datos, es decir evalúas eso contra el hash que se genera de la contraseña que te llega por post

Comment: Te recomiendo usar la función md5('contraseña_aqui'), son 32 caracteres que necesitas.

Comment: @LuisChaves por lo que dices estas comparando una contraseña encriptada por una contraseña normal dentro del `mysqli_query`

Comment: @LuisChaves porque encriptas nuevamente la contraseña? Si ya tienes una en la BD?

Comment: No sabemos cómo están los datos en la BD, sólo nos dices "no me funciona". Así pues, edita la pregunta y añade lo que tienes en la tabla para saber qué pasa.

Comment: listo lo edite..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antes de darte la respuesta hay que entender que significa `password_hash`, segun documentacion:

> password_hash() crea un nuevo hash de contraseña usando un algoritmo de hash fuerte de único sentido

Como dice la ultima parte de **unico sentido** eso quiere decir nunca tendra el mismo valor (Nunca se creara uno igual al otro). Con lo cual en tu BD ya tienes una contraseña con este metodo asi que si pones nuevamente `password_hash` se creara otro completamente diferente a la que hay en tu BD, ahi el error.

Para solucionarlo deberias comparar con un "identificador" para obtener la "contraseña" de tu BD, en este caso seria el "email", ya que en si deberia ser unico, entonces con lo anterior dicho seria el codigo asi:

```
if(isset($_POST['seleccion'])){

    $email = $_POST['correo'];
    $contrasena = $_POST['contraseña'];

    # Creamos el query para obtener la contraseña segun el email
    $stmt = $connex->prepare("SELECT contraseña FROM usuario WHERE email = ?");
    # Le pasamos el email
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($pass_hash);

    # Comparamos si existe una contraseña con ese correo
    if( $stmt->fetch() > 0 )
    {
        # Verificamos si la contraseña ingresada coincide con la que esta en la BD
        if( password_verify($contrasena, $pass_hash) ) {
            echo "Se encontro el usuario, $email.";
        }else{
            echo "no se encontro el usuario";
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "Error, no se encontro la cuenta asociada al correo dado";
    }

 }
```

**Referencia**

- https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.password-hash.php

Answer (score 1):

Estás comparando lo que sea que guardaste en la tabla `logi` como contraseña, con la contraseña sin cifrar

```
SELECT * FROM logi WHERE email='$email' and contraseña='$contrasena'
```

Luego, estás comparando esa contraseña sin cifrar que recibiste **con la que tú mismo cifraste**

```
if (password_verify($contrasena, $encrip)) {
```

Así pues, esa consulta sólo dará resultados si `logi` almacena la contraseña sin cifrar (terrible) y después, igual, estás validando cualquier cosa en ese password_verify porque SIEMPRE va a decir que coinciden. Tú acabas de generar el contenido de `$encrip`.

Lo que yo haría es

a) cambiar la consulta y hacer que busque comparando la contraseña cifrada (**siempre y cuando estés guardando la clave cifrada!!**).

```
SELECT * FROM logi WHERE email='$email' and contraseña='$encrip'
```

b) eliminaría el password_verify porque, si la consulta ya me dijo que son iguales, no estoy haciendo nada adicional.

Comment: amigoo. no me funciona puse como me lo dijiste y  no reconoce la contraseña :(

Comment: en la base de datos tengo contraseñas sin cifrar y cifrados. Los que no estan cifradas funcionan pero los que estan cifradas no funcionan.

Comment: Esto no funcionaria, porque en la BD ya esta una contraseña. Por lo que muestra el codigo del OP esta encriptando nuevamente la contraseña asi que nunca encontrara el usuario

Comment: ose todas las contraseñas de todos los usuarios deben se encriptadas para que funcionen??...

Comment: @LuisChaves POR SUPUESTO. Uno nunca guarda la clave sin cifrar, es un fallo de seguridad y por eso te pregunté arriba cómo guardabas las cosas